# Allow user to only submit a Web Form for Marketers form once

Tags: wffm

Is there a way when creating a form (Web Form for Marketers) to make it so when a person fills out the form and it's successfully submitted that the same person cannot submit the form again?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Sitecore Personalization to hide the form and show different content based on various criteria, like a contact facet that indicates that this particular form has been submitted already. Personalization is a powerful tool that uses the Sitecore Rules Engine to evaluate various conditions. Components can be hidden or shown, have their datasource changed or rendered with a different compatible rendering.

More detail on personalization can be found on the [Sitecore Documentation Site](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/personalization/walkthrough_personalizing_components).

You can also handle that scenario more simply during the form post and return a message if that contact has already submitted that form (or any other relevant condition).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Nathan that you should use Personalization to control the visibility of the form. One option is to use [Goals](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/campaigns/goals__events/goals). When you insert a form the wizard gives you the option to create a new form (or select an existing one):

[image: Set Form Goal]

If you have already added the form then you can add a Goal from the Content Editor using the `Tracking` field.

[image: Set Goal from Content Editor]

You can then use Personalization to hide the form is the Goal has previously been triggered (i.e. the form has been completed). Add a new personalization rule for the component, configure the rule to checked if the Goal has been triggered and then set the action to `Hide`:

[image: Form Completed Personalization Rule]

This relies on the use of xDB, Goals will not be recorded if you are running CMS mode only. You may be able to create a custom Rule in this case to achieve a similar result.